# Resizing iframes inside WebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm trying to display in a `WebView` several html files in one html using iframes

I'm using the following script in the html file in order to resize the height of iframes in the current html.

```
<body onload="resizeFrames()" link="#bb7722" vlink="#bb7722" alink="#bb7722" > 


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Firefox worked fine. Internet Explorer shows scrollbar because of frameborder
        function resizeFrames() {
            var all_IFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            i = 0;
            while (frame = all_IFrames.item(i++)) {
                resizeFrame(frame);
            }            
        }
        function resizeFrame(f) {

            f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    </script>

    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="b.html"></iframe>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="c.html"></iframe>
```

In order the javascript to work I use the foloowing code:

```
WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I load the html file like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html");
```

The problem is that the size of the resized iframes is sometimes too big and somtimes too small.

I tested it on galaxy s with android 2.2 and all the frames were smaller (cut off in the end) and in an other device with android 4.0.4, all the frames were bigger (adding empty space)

If I remove the `webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` the problem in galaxy s disappears, but in the second device, the frames don't resize at all

full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <style>


    body{
    color: #aa6611;
    font-size:20px;
    }

    .link {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bb7722;
    }
    </style>


</head>

<body onload="resizeFrames()" link="#bb7722" vlink="#bb7722" alink="#bb7722" > 


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Firefox worked fine. Internet Explorer shows scrollbar because of frameborder
        function resizeFrames() {
            var all_IFrames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            i = 0;
            while (frame = all_IFrames.item(i++)) {
                resizeFrame(frame);
            }           
        }
        function resizeFrame(f) {
            f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    </script>

    <a name="top"></a>


    <font size = "6" color="#ffaa55">Guide</font>
    <br /> 
    <br />

    <a href="#mainscreen" class="link" >Main screen</a> <br />
    <a href="#inventory" class="link">Inventory</a> <br />
    <a href="#store" class="link">Store</a> <br />
    <a href="#market" class="link">Market</a> <br />
    <a href="#creatureattackdialog" class="link">Creature Attack Dialog</a> <br />
    <a href="#userattackdialog" class="link">User Attack Dialog</a> <br />
    <a href="#miniattackdialog" class="link">Mini Attack Dialog</a> <br />
    <a href="#profile" class="link">Profile</a> <br />
    <a href="#creatureinfo" class="link">Creature info</a> <br />
    <a href="#userinfo" class="link">User info</a> <br />
    <a href="#iteminfo" class="link">Item info</a> <br />
    <a href="#lastattackers" class="link">Last Attackers</a> <br />
    <a href="#achievementshistory" class="link">Achievements History</a> <br />
    <a href="#achievementsDialog" class="link">Achievement info</a> <br />
    <a href="#options" class="link">Options</a> <br />


    <br /> 

    <p>
    <a name="mainscreen"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="mainscreen.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="inventory"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="inventory.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="store"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="store.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="market"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="market.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="creatureattackdialog"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="attackDialogCreature.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="userattackdialog"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="attackDialogUser.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="miniattackdialog"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="miniattackdialog.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="profile"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="profile.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="creatureinfo"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="creatureInfo.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="userinfo"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="userInfo.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="iteminfo"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="itemInfo.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="lastattackers"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="lastattackers.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="achievementshistory"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="acheivementhistory.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="achievementsDialog"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="acheivementDialog.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />

    <p>
    <a name="options"></a>
    <iframe width="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 border=0 src="optionsDialog.html"></iframe>
    </p>
    <a href="#top" class="link">Back</a> <br />



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set listeners for the onload handlers in iframe tags, one for each and resize each one when the iframe not the body was loaded.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('yourIF');
var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
iframe.style.height = (iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight) + "px";
```